# Get post terms with hierarchical relationships

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm having a hard time getting a set of selected terms in a custom taxonomy presented in a specific way.

I have a hierarchical taxonomy 'places' and a post with the tagged terms:

```
England (x)
  - London (x)
     - Venue1 (x)
France (x)
  - Paris (x)
     - Venue2
Germany
  - Berlin (x)
     - Venue3 (x)
```

I need to print out:

```
myPostTitle : Venue1 (London - England)
              Paris (France)
              Venue3 (Berlin)
```

My problem is, that I can't find a function that will return the tagged terms, in a manner that reflects the hierarchical relationships. I need to be able to determine:

- Which terms are the actual 'venues' (the 'lowest' tagged child in each of the hierarchies)
- What parents and grandparents of those 'last children' to include.

I'm outside the loop, and would prefer not to run setup_postdata(). I have the post ID.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're going to find a function that created the exact output you're using, so you're probably looking at two nested called to [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). I usually avoid most other taxonomy-related plugins in favor of get terms. Most of the other functions are wrappers for this one.

Here's some psuedo-code for what I'd do:

```
<?php

// Get all the top-level terms i.e. those without a parent
$top_level_terms = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy', array( 'parent' => 0 ) );

foreach( $top_level_terms as $top_term ) {

    // get child terms. use parent for direct descendants or child_of for all descendents
    $child_terms = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy', array( 'child_of' => $top_term->term_id ));

    // list the parent term    
    printf(
        '<a href="%1$s">%2%s</a> (',
        esc_url( get_term_link( $top_term->term_id ) ),
        esc_attr( $top_term->name )
    );

    // list all the child terms
    foreach ( $child_terms as $child_term ) {
        printf(
            '<a href="%1$s">%2%s</a>, ',
            esc_url( get_term_link( $child_term->term_id ) ),
            esc_attr( $child_term->name )
        );
    }

    echo ')';

}
```

That code's untested and surely needs some additional arguments from you, but hopefully that can get you started.